# Is there a matlab function that does the same as diff but with a 2-step? i.e. get X(n)-X(n-2) instead of X(n)-X(n-1)

Tags: matlab, double, difference

I have a vector (let's call it v) in which the elements are equal to 0 most of the time, but it can also have sequences of 1 and sequences of 2. I am trying to detect the indexes where it starts to be equal to 2.

I tried to do:

```
ind = find(diff(v) == 2);
```

But it does not work:

> ans =   1×0 empty double row vector

It is because of my vector v. Its elements never go from 0 to 2 directly, there is always a "buffer" element equal to 1 in-between, so it looks like:
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 ...

I am looking for a function that can do the same as diff but returns X(n)-X(n-2) instead of X(n)-X(n-1) to solve my problem, or any other solution

Comment: Why do you need a difference? Why does `find(v==2)` not suffice?

Comment: Because I would have too many outputs as it can be equal to 2 for hundreds of indexes.. I just want the index of the beginning of the sequence of 2

Comment: @YannTC As the documentation explains, you can tell `find` how many outpus you want (e.g. only the first). `find(v==2,1)`. Or you could just index `ind` as `ind(1)`, that is the first. Your attempted solution seems to be the most complicated possible one.

Comment: There's no such function that I know of, but it's easy to do it manually: `step = 2; result = v(1+step:end)-v(1:end-step);`

Comment: So you cannot have `1 1 2`?

Comment: @Bebs correct, I have always only one '1' before my sequence of 2

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for your answer, it works

Comment: Glad it works. I just posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such function that I know of, but it's easy to do it manually:

```
v = [6 9 4 8 5 2 5 7]; % example data
step = 2; % desired step
result = v(1+step:end)-v(1:end-step); % get differences with that step
```

As an alternative (thanks to [@CrisLuengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) for the tip), you could use convolution as follows:

```
result = conv(v, [1 zeros(1,step-1) -1], 'valid');
```

Comment: I’m surprised you’re not suggesting to use your favorite `conv`!

Comment: @CrisLuengo How didn't I think of that! Solved :-)

Comment: I love the use of `conv`! +1.

Answer (score 0):

`ind = find(diff(v) == 2);` will highlight indices where the value of v has increased by 2.

You need to detect values equal to 2, then use diff to seek the first value. `ind = find(diff(v == 2));` is closer to your needs.

The following code should work fine:

```
%Make a logical vector, true if v equal 2
valueIs2 = (v==2);

%Make a logical vector where:
% First value is true if the vector v starts with 2
% The next values are true only if this is the first 2 of a sequence
isStartOfSequence = [v(1) diff(v)>0];

%another equivalent option:
isStartOfSequence = [v(1) (v(2:end) & ~v(1:end-1))];

% Use find to convert logical to indices
indicesStartOfSequence = find(isStartOfSequence);
```